# scale in and scale out objects individually with same sliders in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been trying to implement a scale and rotate slider which can scale and rotate objects individually. The scale and rotate slider element should be the same for all the objects. But it should scale or rotate one object one at a time.

Comment: So what is the issue you're having?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How would you switch between the objects? a Dropdown? or clicking on them?

Comment: by dropdown on them

Answer (score 0):

First add a [Dropdown](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown.html) to your Canvas. Then two [Sliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html) for rotating and scaling respectively.

Then create a MonoBehaviour `ScalerRotater` with three methods `OnScaleChanged`, `OnRotateChanged` and `OnObjectChanged`. Connect the `OnValueChanged` in the Inspector window of the Sliders and Dropdowns to each of those methods.

The `OnObjectChanged` will keep track of which object is selected, you'll need a `List<GameObject>` to keep track of all the available GameObjects. The other two methods will scale and rotate the object (don't forget to check for null).

Comment: Can u help me with the practical application of it

Comment: That's not what stackoverflow is about. If you are new to unity I can recommend [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlKaB1etrik&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5QFsefuO2RlAgWEz6EvVi6&index=2).